# c# is it possible to lazy load function parameter after calling the function?

Tags: c#, .net, lazy-loading, lazy-evaluation, lazy-initialization

I was wondering if it possible in C# to lazy load the parameter of a function after calling the function. In fact I want the parameter of the function to be loaded only when I use the output of the function.
I try to explain what I mean with the following example:

```
        var a = Enumerable.Range(1, 10);
        int take = 5;
        var lazyTake = new Lazy<int>(() => take);

        // here I still don't iterate on Enumerable, I want the parameter of function Take be initialized later when I start iterating
        var b = a.Take(lazyTake.Value);

        // here I initialize (change) the value of parameter take
        take = 6;   

        Console.WriteLine(b.ToList().Count);  // I want b to have 6 elements but it's 5
```

Here `Lazy<int>` is not doing what I need. Does anyone know any workaround or language feature to support such a case?

Comment: Could you elaborate the exact use case for this? @usr already gave an answer that works, but I'm curious in what situation you'd like to be able to change a parameter value after the fact. Or: is this just a toy example demonstrating the behavior you want, but in the actual use-case your values are not varying over time but are potentially perhaps expensive to compute?

Comment: @ShinNoNoir the use case as you could guess is indeed when calculating the `take` number is some expensive task and you only want to do that if the object is being used (in this case `b` but it can be a class property).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Take<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Lazy<int> count) { 
    var takeSequence = source.Take(count.Value);
    foreach (var item in takeSequence) yield return item;
}
```

This is fully lazy. The body of this function will only execute when you start enumerating because this is an iterator method. Only then will the lazy `count` be forced to materialize.

Instead of a `Lazy` you could pass a `Func<int> getTakeCount` parameter as well.

Comment: Wow! this is surprisingly working! Thanks a lot! Here the surprising thing for me is that when I use `return source.Take(count.value);` the lazy variable `count` would be evaluated but with your implementation, the evaluation will be postponed until the enumerable is being iterated! Any explanation?

Comment: It's an iterator method. It's execution is driven by enumerating the return value.

Comment: Extension methods must be __static__ (_and must be defined in non-nested static class_). So @usr please update the method definition as static or don't make the method an extension method.

Comment: @usr thanks for fast action. This question is high on "lazy load" search list on google. I wanted to inform soon, therefore sorry if i sounded too robotic.

Comment: @Letitbe no, that's fine. You can also edit yourself on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1):

Lazy realizes it's value at the time you access the .Value property. So at the time you call a.Take, you've gotten the actual int value 5. Changing the `take` variable won't help at this point, the laziness is gone.

You need a function that will take a `Lazy<T>`, not a `T`. You can probably write one without too much trouble if you understand how to implement `IEnumerable<T>`, but there's nothing built into the framework I know of to suit your scenario.

Comment: Do you mean something like this:
`public IEnumerable<T> Take<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Lazy<int> count)
  {
   return source.Take(count.Value);
  }`

Comment: Almost - doing `return source.Take(count.Value)` will just do exactly the same thing. You'll need to actually implement the IEnumerator (use the yield statement) so that the lazy isn't resolved until you actually enumerate the entire sequence.

Answer (score 1):

Everything is right, the value is initializing lazily, but the problem is the value is being evaluated when you call a.take(lazyTake.Value) because you're passing it as a parameter to a function and it must be evaluated.

The best you can do is surround it with a lambda and execute the lambda at the end:

```
    var a = Enumerable.Range(1, 10);
    int take = 5;

    // here I still don't iterate on Enumerable, I want the parameter of function Take be initialized later when I start iterating
    Func<IEnumerable<int>>  getResult = () => a.Take(take);

    // here I initialize (change) the value of parameter take
    take = 6;   

    Console.WriteLine(getResult().ToList().Count);
```

EDIT: cannot use var for the lambda, just use Func to make it work

Comment: Thanks Gusman! This is interesting but the problem is the variable `b` in my example is no longer an `IEnumerable<int>` and it would be a `Func<IEnumerable<int>>`. I still want `b` to have type `IEnumerable<int>`. Assume `b` is a class variable and you want to initialize it with an `IEnumerable<int>` but you still don't know how many elements you need to take.

Comment: easy: b = getResult().ToList();